# Update Statistics full scan hung up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics

We have a weekly maintenance plan that does your typical Integrity Checks and then goes and does an Update Statistics on all the databases on our server.

Over the weekend it appears that our job was hung up on the Update Statistics (with full scan) job. Looking at the Activity Monitor it appeared to have a Task State of SUSPENDED for the command Update Statistics. And for a Wait Type was LCK_M_X.

My Question: Why would it be suspended? A lock on a table in the database it was doing statistics on couldn't have stopped it? What would hang an update statistics?

Comment: We have steps that are triggered if the particular step (update stats) fails, and it never got to that point so all evidence points to the update stats being hung up.

Comment: Did you look for blocking?

Comment: is `auto update statistics` turned ON ? A `LCK_M_X` wait means a thread is waiting to be granted an exclusive lock on something. You should look at the resource associated using `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` DMV. Check [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) blog post from Paul.

Comment: yes auto update statistics is turned on

Comment: Is it sync or async?

Comment: It is currently set at sync

Comment: You might consider using async, that way it doesn't get involved in the chain of transactions involving dependent objects. With sync, the query must wait for the stats to run, which - if it takes a long time, or if that query blocks others - can become a big snowball.

Comment: Why are you doing update stats with fullscan every weekend? What is auto-update not solving? Do you have an ascending key problem? Have you proven that the fullscan update actually helps? How big is the table that caused the problem (sum of CIX + NCIXs)? Did you check the default trace for autogrow events (for the database's data/log files, or tempdb)?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand for your help. Unfortunately this is a recently inherited server so as to some of the reasoning for setting things up the way they are I can't answer. It does seem all the db's have auto stats on so I'm not sure why they thought a full scan every weekend was necessary.

Comment: @Andy honestly I would just turn that job off and enable it for tables where you can actually demonstrate that there are performance issues without doing it manually. There can be many reasons why you'd want to manually update stats, but I think it is much worse to just blindly do it for everything.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes we have a lot of work ahead of us getting a grasp of everything that is going on with this server. Could an exclusive lock combined with auto stats in sync mode cause the update stats job to hang like that? Or does an exclusive lock stop update stats from working regardless of sync vs async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to determine that only one table in the database in question had not had it's statistics updated. We did that by running the following

```
select object_name (i.id)as objectname,i.name as indexname,i.origfillfactor,i.rowcnt,i.rowmodctr ,STATS_DATE(i.id, i.indid) as ix_Statistics_Date,o.instrig,o.updtrig,o.deltrig,o.seltrig
from sysindexes i INNER JOIN dbo.sysobjects o ON i.id = o.id
where rowcnt >1000 and i.name not like'sys%'and object_name(i.id)not like'sys%'
order by objectname desc
go
```

So we ran the update statistics on just the table in question. And we were able to replicate the scenario in question as it was still waiting and not finishing. So then knowing the session ID of my waiting process I took a look at the locks table

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_locks
```

Looking at the results I found a different session ID associated with the Object_ID of my table in question. I was able to then go kill that session ID and the update statistics finished no problem.

What I think happened here was that a user left a program open that had the exclusive lock on my table, and perhaps that along with auto statistics in sync mode may have caused a log jam when doing our full scan update stats.

Comment: So the other session was blocking it. You should try to figure out what that session was doing - you don't want to have to manually kill a session every time this happens.